# Json_agg as single object

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have following table:

```
create table tickets (id integer, key text, value text);

insert into tickets values
(1, 'CUSTOMER_ID', 3242),
(1, 'AMOUNT', 49),
(1, 'MOVIE', 'TITANIC');
```

expected output:

```
{"CUSTOMER_ID": "3242", "AMOUNT": "49", "MOVIE": "TITANIC"}
```

If the data in the table would be stored in separated columns the simple json_build_object('name', column_name) would work, but here I have various number of rows (and they may be different for each ID)

So this one doesn't work as I want

```
select json_agg(jsonb_build_object(key, value)) from tickets where id = 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a2140d9d9ecf7adcec13cbb1d86215c8

Comment: use `json_object_agg` instead of `json_build_object` see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select jsonb_object_agg(key, value) from tickets where id = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, actually it should be without json_build_object at all

Comment: agree with you !

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
SELECT id,
       jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
FROM tickets
GROUP BY id;
```